# how to copy files from current batch file location to new path

Tags: batch-file

I am new to write batch files. Can you please help me with the below scenario.

I have a batch file and some `.dll` and `.txt` files in one folder in my machine. when i run the batch file all the files in the current folder(batch file exist folder) has to move to different folder in some other machine(we need to give the destination path from UI)

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: it is unclear what you want.

Comment: What OS are you running the script from? What OS does the machine you are copying files to run? What software do the machines have installed? Are you free to install any software on both machines?

Comment: Thanks Raul for your quick response. this is scenario which we are trying .We are using windows 07 machines. we are having 2 machines client and server and installing our product in server.  after installation of product in server some folders will get created  with all the respective files. in that we are having 1 folder named "common". we are planning to put batch file in common with installation only . After installing product in server when we go to common folder and run the batch file all the files in the common folder has to move to client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enter source and destination in prompt:

```
@echo off
set /p "mysource=Enter Source: "
set /p "mydest=Enter destination: "
move /Y "%mysource%\*.dll" "%mydest%"
move /Y "%mysource%\*.txt" "%mydest%"
```

if you want to just prompt for destination:

```
@echo off
set /p "mydest=Enter destination: "
move /Y "C:\path to files\subdirs\*.dll" "%mydest%"
move /Y "C:\path to files\subdirs\*.txt" "%mydest%"
```

if all the `.txt` and `.dll` files are in the same directory as the batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p "mydest=Enter destination: "
move /Y "*.dll" "%mydest%"
move /Y "*.txt" "%mydest%"
```

Where destination can be a drive or UNC path. i.e:

```
move /Y C:\somepath\*.txt "G:\Some folder\"
```

or

```
move /Y C:\somepath\*.txt "\\devicename\Some folder\"
```

Comment: Thank you So much Gerhand. It is working and 1 more small doubt. after running the batch file if i have some files already located in the destination folder and if i want to over ride them how can we do it

Comment: @dinesh the `/Y` takes care of that already to see that, do `move /?` and read the help